# What happens with data received by the server using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, http-post

`one.php`:

HTML:

```
<button value="testValue" name="foo">Click</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var keyVals = {foo:"bar"}
        $(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"two.php",
                    data: keyVals,
                    success: function() {
                        $("#center").append("<p>Data Transfer succeeded! </p>");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Now, what actually happens with the data? How can I use it in `two.php`? Say I want to save it in a file/database, why not save it directly from `one.php`?
I've tried the following:

`two.php`:

```
    <?php
        var_dump($_REQUEST);
    ?>
```

Comes out as empty. So what ACTUALLY happens with the data I sent from `one.php`? How can I use it?

Strangely enough, I've looked at every similar question to this I could find, and none of them were answered properly, and most of them were downvoted. What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1):

send data like this -

```
data: { value : $(this).val() },
```

on php access it like this -

```
$value = $_POST["value"];
```

Comment: if I use echo $_POST["value"] I get: "Undefined index: foo". If I use var_dump($_POST) it just says the array is empty.